# How to parse URL params in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have tried the same successfully in python to parse URL params but I would like to know if there is a way to do the same in Shell Script.

Say, I have a URL value:

http://www.abcdsample.com/listservices?a=1&b=10&c=abcdeeff&d=1663889&listservices=a|b

Required Output:

```
URL: http://www.abcdsample.com/
Service: listservices
a=1
b=10
c=abcdeeff
d=1663889
listservices=a|b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
BEGIN{
    FS="?"
}
{
    url=$1
    sub(/[^/]*$/,"",url)
    print "URL:",url

    sub(/.*[/]/,"",$1)
    print "Service:",$1

    n=split($2,b,/&/)
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        print b[i]
}
```

Save it as `script.awk` and run like `awk -f script.awk file`:

```
URL: http://www.abcdsample.com/
Service: listservices
a=1
b=10
c=abcdeeff
d=1663889
listservices=a|b
```

Note: this will work for URL like:

- http://www.abcdsample.com/listservices?a=1&b=10&c=abcdeeff&d=1663889&listservices=a|b
- www.abcdsample.com/listservices?a=1&b=10&c=abcdeeff&d=1663889&listservices=a|b
- abcdsample.com/listservices?a=1&b=10&c=abcdeeff&d=1663889&listservices=a|b
- listservices?a=1&b=10&c=abcdeeff&d=1663889&listservices=a|b

Comment: Thanks. This works for the specific requirement. I would like to know if there is a way to send in the URL as a param to the script

Comment: @user1652054 many ways? How would you like to do it? You could do `echo "$url" | awk -f script.awk` or `awk -f script.awk <<< "$url"` where `$url` can be a shell variable or the literal URL.

Answer (score 2):

One way with GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -F'&' '{
   $0 = gensub(/(^[^/]+[/][/][^/]+[/])([^?]+)[?]/,"\\1\\&\\2\\&","")
   print "URL:",$1
   print "Service:",$2
   for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)
      print $i
}' file
URL: http://www.abcdsample.com/
Service: listservices
a=1
b=10
c=abcdeeff
d=1663889
listservices=a|b
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not that good in awk/regex. It would be helpful if you can explain how to tweak the same to handle URLS that would just have - listservices?a=1&b=10&c=abcdeeff&d=1663889&listservices=a|b or /listservices?a=1&b=10&c=abcdeeff&d=1663889&listservices=a|b essentially without a domain name info

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to figure it out your self if you're interested (it is a very simple tweak). It's important when you post a question to include some representative input and expected output. When you leave out important variations of input and then reveal that your input doesn't match what you posted AFTER we've posted an answer that works for that input, it's really inconsiderate and irritating so some of us will lose interest in trying to help you. In this case you asked for help parsing a URL, posted a sample URL and now are asking to "tweak" it for input that's not a URL. Come on.

Comment: Thanks. Will do so. Sorry about the lack of clarity and 'tweak' request.