# package to query tab separated files in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, awk

I often have to conduct very simple queries on tab separated files in bash. For example summing/counting/max/min all the values in the n-th column. I usually do this in awk via command-line, but I've grown tired of re-writing the same one line scripts over and over and I'm wondering if there is a known package or solution for this.

For example, consider the text file (test.txt):

```
apples   joe    4
oranges  bill   3
apples   sally  2
```

I can query this as:

```
awk '{ val += $3 } END { print "sum: "val }' test.txt
```

Also, I may want a where clause:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == "apples") { val += $3 } END { print "sum: "val }' test.txt
```

Or a group by:

```
awk '{ val[$1] += $3 } END { for(k in val) { print k": "val[k] } }' test.txt
```

What I would rather do is:

```
query 'sum($3)' test.txt
query 'sum($3) where $1 = "apples"' test.txt
query 'sum($3) group by $1' test.txt
```

@Wintermute posted a link to a great tool for this in the comments below. Unfortunately it does have one drawback:

```
$ time gawk '{ a += $6 } END { print a }' my1GBfile.tsv 
28371787287

real    0m2.276s
user    0m1.909s
sys 0m0.313s

$ time q -t 'select sum(c6) from my1GBfile.tsv'
28371787287

real    3m32.361s
user    3m27.078s
sys 0m1.983s
```

it also loads the entire file into memory, obviously this will be necessary in some cases, but doesn't work for me as I often work with large files.

Comment: Writing a translator from your desired input to the corresponding awk scripts would seem to be (for simple inputs at least) fairly straightforward.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, I started this, but if one exists already it would be preferable

Comment: You could put the data in a database, no? Then you could do queries in SQL more or less as in your examples, except with names instead of $1.

Comment: There are [tools](https://harelba.github.io/q/) that can perform SQL queries directly on CSV files.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15765479/1745001

Comment: You can put your awk command in a shell script. Then you only have to pass the variables to that shell script.

Comment: @Wintermute Good answer. Can you add it as a separate answer so it's easier for everyone to know that this has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

[Wintermute's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) answer: Tools like [q](https://harelba.github.io/q/) that can run SQL queries directly on CSVs.

[Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) answer: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15765479/1745001